# Drawing on Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, draw

I have this code that simply creates new panel and implements custom draw function.

```
centerPanel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
         public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2.setColor(Color.blue);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
            g2.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

            Map<Integer, String> tables = Controller.FormMainWindowGetTables();
            for (Integer id : tables.keySet()) {
                Map<String, Object> table = Controller.FormMainWindowGetSingleTable(id);
                g2.drawOval((int)table.get("pos_x"), (int)table.get("pos_y"), 100, 100);
            }
         }
    };
```

But it only draws a single oval. I also tried putting debug text inside the loop to see how it works, but it only outputs information on the first element. It seems like the loop is "infinite" but only always outputs the first element of the `Map`.

I just can't figure out what is wrong here...

Comment: `Controller.FormMainWindowGetSingleTable(id)` why this is even necessary ? what is wrong with `tables.get(id)` And check whither index and `table` instances are differing: that is they don't have same co-ordinate

Comment: This is needed because it returns a particular table details such as its position.

Comment: Please try posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which is able to produce your problem for better help sooner

Comment: Try placing what's returned by `tables.keySet()` in a local variable just before the loop and check its contents when debugging.